# Interpretation of probability in geostatistics

Tags: probability, bayesian, interpretation, frequentist, geostatistics

In geostatistics, the concept of a random field is used in e.g. Kriging. Hence, at each point in your study area, there is a probability distribution. Should this probability be given a frequentistic or a Bayesian interpretation (or maybe both are possible)? I think the frequentistic interpretation of probability is difficult here (which experiment, and under which circumstances, can you (conceptually) repeat here many times?). Example: suppose you are interested in predicting the concentration of a chemical substance in the soil. I don't understand how the 'genesis' of the chemical substance at a particular point can be interpreted as a probabilistic process with a frequentistic interpretation.

Comment: The difficulty is overcome by the [ergodic assumption.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process).

Comment: I don't think that the ergodic assumption is helpful here. Suppose you are interested in a certain ore grade. The ore grade will generally not change over time. Also, repeated meausements of the ore grade at the same location will give approximately the same result. However, the genesis of the ore grade at a certain location is interpreted as a probabilistic process. But I don't understand how you can give this probabilistic process a frequentistic interpretation.

Comment: @WordA your question is interesting, but hard to answer without knowing the geostatics context (I guess this is why you didn't get any response yet). It would be probably easier to answer if you provided such context (e.g. detailed example).

Comment: A interesting paper on this subject is ["Is soil variation random?"](http://mmc2.geofisica.unam.mx/cursos/geoest/Articulos/Geostatistics/Is%20soil%20variation%20random.pdf) from R. Webster. He says that the formation of the soil is deterministic (except at the sub-atomic level), but that the complexity of the factors (that contributed to the soil as we see it) in combination, their variation over the time, and the incompleteness of our knowledge, that the outcome, the soil, appears to us as if it were random. This seems like a Bayesian interpretation of probability to me.

Comment: I think that a frequentist interpretation is difficult, because it is not clear to me which experiment you could conceptually repeat many times in soil formation.

Comment: The ergodic assumption is the *only* assumption that allows one to justify a (non-subjective) probability model for a random field.  That's why this is invariably discussed in any textbook on geostatistics.  Repeated measurements are just that--measurements, which are subject to a separate (and independent) variability--so they should not be confused with the structure of the field.

Comment: Okay, to derive properties of your random field, you have to make assumptions. But at different locations, you have different probability distributions. So the measurements are observations coming from different probability distributions (and, of course, you only have one realisation of the random field). I asked the question above because I am not sure how you can interpret probabilities in geostatistics.

Comment: Matheron wrote a book trying to answer your question:  https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540500872